# How to fix bin/sh: can't create /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied when running docker-compose?

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I intended to use Laravel and I wanted to use laradock. After some successful setup processes.

I meant to run `docker-compose up` but I got this error

```
Building ide-theia
Step 1/3 : FROM theiaide/theia
 ---> 40a7b9da8cae
Step 2/3 : LABEL maintainer="ahkui <ahkui@outlook.com>"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d9d45043f719
Step 3/3 : RUN echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
 ---> Running in 4dd5bcc59773
/bin/sh: can't create /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
ERROR: Service 'ide-theia' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' >> /etc/sysctl.conf' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I didn't know why. No matter I used `sudo` or didn't, the error still appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got the way to fix it. Go to Laradock folder > ide-theia > Dockerfile. Add this command

```
USER root
```

before this command

```
RUN echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Save it, try to run `docker-compose up` again.

See this issue fixed at https://github.com/laradock/laradock/commit/df49e2fd83c15cb11691b03673f5d432a8cbafd6?fbclid=IwAR2z2z0EfOdP6bVd-ZIRIkE158HfKxXrB9pdNwqD0NYD9B7tRY3rKMCaDEA

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1841) & [fixed](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/pull/1842/commits/df49e2fd83c15cb11691b03673f5d432a8cbafd6) Laradock issue.
You should [update Laradock](https://laradock.io/documentation/#upgrading-laradock).

Comment: Sure. I just didn't know why. This was new laradock installation. I did it last night. I got this issue addressed at https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1841?fbclid=IwAR2tbJvtlW_l-nsfl22HvOFtJjfHobzUVffLBAqbkYIems5jBglJVQHehCA. And now the error is gone.